# Multiple S2S Connections for Azure

Tags: networking, azure, ipsec, site-to-site-vpn, azure-networking

I’m confused by all of this and need help. I setup an Azure S2S tunnel from Azure to my On Prem DC. This is for AD and AAD to sync. We have a new billing system coming in and the only way they’ll allow SSO is an IPSec tunnel.

How do I add an additional connection to them?  I see the tutorials on how I built what I have already but nothing with my particular scenario. When it’s asking for a local network gateway, I have control over that on my original setup but they do for this setup. Do I still create a local gateway with information they give me?  When I was trying to set this up with no guidance, I kept getting errors with duplicate connections and couldn’t save.

Any help is appreciated.

Adding more info and hoping someone can help.  Attached is a diagram of what I am trying to accomplish.
[image]